# PGFPlots weighted linear regression error

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I'm doing three weighted linear regressions, and the second two are giving me substantially the same answer as I calculate offline, with the first being very wrong.

What have I done wrong? As far as I can tell, everything is the same, and just copy/pasted, with different data. I've reproduced everything below, with the black line from PGFPlots, and the red line (desired behaviour) from my offline calculations.

The column U is standard deviation, V is variance.

[image: The three plots]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}


\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%This one doesn't work
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
]
\addplot[   
    only marks,
    error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,
] 
table[
    x = X,
    y = Y,
    y error = U,
]
{
X   Y   U   V
10  34.893  0.6 0.360
20  31.263  1.134   1.286
30  49.149  1.807   3.265
40  53.969  2.717   7.382
50  68.956  2.228   4.964
}; 
\addplot[]
table[
    x = X,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y, variance=V}},
]
{
X   Y   U   V
10  34.893  0.6 0.360
20  31.263  1.134   1.286
30  49.149  1.807   3.265
40  53.969  2.717   7.382
50  68.956  2.228   4.964
};
\addplot[red]
table[
    x = X,
    y = yhat,
]
{
X   yhat
10  33.111
20  40.209
30  47.307
40  54.405
50  61.503
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%This one does work
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
]
\addplot[   
    only marks,
    error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,
] 
table[
    x = X,
    y = Y,
    y error = U,
]
{
X   Y   U   V
10  10.147  0.848   0.719
20  15.049  0.768   0.590
30  28.045  1.008   1.016
40  34.733  1.778   3.161
50  42.145  2.386   5.693
}; 
\addplot[]
table[
    x = X,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y, variance=V}},
]
{
X   Y   U   V
10  10.147  0.848   0.719
20  15.049  0.768   0.590
30  28.045  1.008   1.016
40  34.733  1.778   3.161
50  42.145  2.386   5.693
};
\addplot[red]
table[
    x = X,
    y = yhat,
]
{
X   yhat
10  8.813
20  17.356
30  25.899
40  34.441
50  42.984
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%This one does work
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
]
\addplot[   
    only marks,
    error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,
] 
table[
    x = X,
    y = Y,
    y error = U,
]
{
X   Y   U   V
10  16.983  0.417   0.174
20  24.753  0.977   0.955
30  39.675  1.796   3.226
40  38.524  3.838   14.730
50  48.147  3.02    9.120
}; 
\addplot[]
table[
    x = X,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y, variance=V}},
]
{
X   Y   U   V
10  16.983  0.417   0.174
20  24.753  0.977   0.955
30  39.675  1.796   3.226
40  38.524  3.838   14.730
50  48.147  3.02    9.120
};
\addplot[red]
table[
    x = X,
    y = yhat,
]
{
X   yhat
10  16.994
20  25.642
30  34.290
40  42.938
50  51.587
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The data was analysed offline as follows, using the first data set add an example:

[image]

where T is the transpose, and -1 is the inverse.

The weights are simply the inverse square of the standard deviation. The intercept is 26.01, and the slope 0.710; this is the equation of the red line in my first plot.

Comment: @marmot image added

Comment: @marmot the desired output is the red line. In the other two cases, the actual and desired are close enough.

Comment: @marmot Mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I took the first three columns of the first data set and fit them off-line (using Igor Pro). I did an unweighted fit and a weighted fit using the standard deviations as weightings. Below are the results (black is unweighted and red is weighted).

[image: A plot of data from first set generated using Igor Pro. Black is unweighted and red is weighted.]

Neither of the lines exactly agree with either of your results. The weighted line I get is *close* to what you have from the off-line weighted fit. I suggest that one issue is at play in this case. Using variances versus standard uncertainties as weighting factors exposes the algorithm to round-off errors. By reference to your comment of *close enough* for the other two plots, did you use standard uncertainties as weightings during the off-line fitting and use variances with PFGPlots? This does matter!

Otherwise, I cannot imagine why the fit fails. I compiled your example on my system and got the same result as you did. I changed the order of the graphs (putting the bad one last) and still had an incorrect fit. Finally, I increased the significance of the variances (e.g. 4.96398) and changed the order of the points. Still I had failure. My only other finding is this: When you change the variance of the last data point to 2, the fit line parallels the external fit line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%This one doesn't work
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
]
\addplot[   
    only marks,
    error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,
] 
table[
    x = X,
    y = Y,
    y error = U,
]
{
X   Y   U   V
10  34.893  0.6 0.360
20  31.263  1.134   1.286
30  49.149  1.807   3.265
40  53.969  2.717   7.382
50  68.956  2.228   4.964
}; 
\addplot[]
table[
    x = X,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y, variance=V}},
]
{
X   Y   U   V
10  34.893  0.6 0.360
20  31.263  1.134   1.286
30  49.149  1.807   3.265
40  53.969  2.717   7.382
50  68.956  2.228   2
};
\addplot[red]
table[
    x = X,
    y = yhat,
]
{
X   yhat
10  33.111
20  40.209
30  47.307
40  54.405
50  61.503
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Perhaps you have discovered a bug in PFGPlots?

Comment: Thanks. I've added how I did my analysis. The weightings are the inverse square of the standard deviation (inverse of the variance).

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger could this be a bug?

Comment: @masher - In my analysis, the weights are the inverse of the standard uncertainties. The fit is done using a Levenberg-Marquardt chi-squared optimization. The difference between _close enough_ and _exactly the same_ is to be appreciated here. The reason your answers and mine are NOT _exactly the same_ must be due to round-off errors or differences in the underlying algorithm.

Comment: The difference is probably due to you using different weightings to me, not to round-off errors.

Comment: The deviations are squared to become variances.